# How can I solve these errors

Tags: flutter, provider, appdata

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  TextEditingController userCurrentLocationTextEditingContrpller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController photoShootLocationTextEditingControler = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    
    String placeAddress = Provider.of<AppData>(context).userCurrentLocation.placeName ?? "";
    userCurrentLocationTextEditingContrpller.text = placeAddress;
}
```

But I get these errors:

```
Error: 'AppData' isn't a type.
    String placeAddress = Provider.of<AppData>(context).userCurrentLocation.placeName ?? "";

Error: The getter 'Provider' isn't defined for the class '_SearchScreenState'.

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Provider'.
    String placeAddress = Provider.of<AppData>(context).userCurrentLocation.placeName ?? "";
```

Comment: Please edit your tags. `appdata` is completely irrelevant (it's meant for "questions relating to the user application data folders"). `provider` is "DO NOT USE — this tag is being cleaned up"; use something like `flutter-provider`, if that applies.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to add imports to the file.
For Provider try adding something like

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
```

Than you should also import your AppData in the file. I can't really guess what this import will look like, but your IDE might suggest it to you. For example in VScode if you click on the AppData  - a lightbulb will appear and upon clicking it, it will suggest to import a package with AppData you are looking for